# I am trying to make a simple chat program with c and sockets. When I run it after a couple of things it says program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server, exc-bad-access

```
printf("what is your name?");
    gets(send_name);

    strcpy(send_name2, strcat("You are connected to ", send_name));
    send(connected, send_name2, strlen(send_name2), 0);
```

The other executable is not receiving what i sent...

```
nbytes_recieved = recv(sock, recv_name, 50 ,0);
recv_name[nbytes_recieved] = '\0';
```

This is the code I used in the client code to let it receive the string.

Thanks,
Sidd

Comment: When posting these sort of question it helps to post more of the code. For instance how is `send_name` defined?

Comment: For the love of Turing, never use `gets(3)`!

Comment: @Mr. Shickadance, send_name is defined as a character array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcat` expects as its first argument a writeable buffer. What you give to it is a constant string, probably stored somewhere in a read-only area of the process. The function attempts to write right after this constant string, which results in a memory access violation.

Answer (score 2):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is equivalent of a segmentation fault, usually a NULL pointer dereference, or accessing memory not allocated to the process.  This could be caused if `recv_name` is too small to hold all the bytes received plus the terminating '\0'.

To get started debugging, compile with debugging symbols, and start examining the contents of recv_name at various points in that code.